# Retrieve actual value in hashmap collision

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, hashmap

Two different objects can have same hashCode and are equal. How to fetch the actual object by its reference ?

For example :-

```
class Dog {
    public String name;
    public Dog(String n){
       this.name = n;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if((o instanceof Dog) && ((Dog)o).name.length() == this.name.length()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int hashCode(){
        return name.length();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return name;
    }
}
public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        Map<Object, Object> m = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        Dog d1 = new Dog("clover");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("abcdef");
        m.put(d1, new Dog("aiko1"))
        m.put(d2, new Dog("aiko"));
        System.out.println(m.get(d1));
        System.out.println(m.get(d2));
   }
}
```

OutPut :- 
aiko 
aiko

The value of d1 however is aiko1 but when we fetch, the value printed is aiko. How can we fetch actual d1 value ?

Comment: I don't get your question. You already have `d1`. You're using it as the key.

Comment: The defect is your `equals()` method. You said that Dog("clover")` is the same as Dog("abcdef"). So what do you expect?  The keys d2 and d1 are one and the same!  Therefore m.put(d2,...) replaces entry (d1, Dog("aiko1")).

Comment: I am trying to understand how hashmap works if two objects have same hashcode ? By Hashcode contract if hashcode is same then through equals method objects should be same. Is there a way by which i can retrieve the d1 value in java when hashcodes are same ?

Comment: Did you really intend to assert that two dogs are equal if their names are the same length?  So that Fido is equal to Spot, for example?  That seems an odd assertion to me.

Comment: The above example is just for understanding that two objects in real case scenarios can have same hashcode and are equal. So how can we retrieve the value of individual objects ? Is that possible ?

Comment: If two objects are equal, then only one of them can be a key in a `HashMap`.  You won't be able to retrieve them both.

Comment: _"By Hashcode contract if hashcode is same then through equals method objects should be same."_ This is wrong! The opposite is true: If two objects are equal, then they must have the same hash code. The hash code method should make some effort to produce different hash codes for unequal objects, but they could be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain you how `HashMap` is working in this case.

- First you have overridden `hashCode()` method
- `HashMap` will look it first.
- You are using `length` of `name` field as hash code.
- "clover" and "abcdef" both will return same hash code and that is 6.
- Now its a collision state hence `HashMap` will fall down to `equals` method to check it further that is again overridden by you.
- But here again in `equals` you are doing same thing. Here also you are comparing length of `name` field.
- In this case both the keys are same hence it will override the last value.

You can validate it but calling `m.size()` in the end of `main` method.

---

But I suggest to use `String` as a key that is name field.

```
Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

In this case you don't need to override `hashCode` as well as `equals`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Dog {
    public String name;

    public Dog(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Dog d1 = new Dog("clover");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("abcdef");
        m.put(d1.name, new Dog("aiko1"));
        m.put(d2.name, new Dog("aiko"));
        System.out.println(m.get(d1.name));
        System.out.println(m.get(d2.name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both your keys (`d1` and `d2`) are equal (according to your implementation of of `eqauls(Object)`), there aren't two elements in the map - only one. The second call to `put` **overrides** the previous value.